# Javascript functions to retrieve diffrent html elements by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to write a Javascript functions that will be able to retrieve elemetns by Id. For instance, i want to write 2 functions one to retrieve Label elements by Id and one to retrieve input elements by Id. The reason that i want to separate them is mainly because i want to have access to their properties.

```
Label = function(id) {     


 this.id = id;

   this.setValue = function(value) {
        $("#" + id).text(value);
    }

}

function Label(id) {

        var elem = $('#'+id).val();
        if (elem == null) {
            alert('Label with id = ' + id + ' does not exist!');
        } else
            return new Label(id);
    }
```

the problem with the above function is that if i write an input element Id it will return the input element with the labels function. So my question is how can i make a kind of validation in order to prevent incorrect element Id's in my label function?

Comment: You don't need functions for this, just use jQuery, and make sure your ID's are ***unique*** !

Comment: The _label_ should be using a _for_ attribute, not an _id_ attribute; input: `#foo`, label: `label[for="foo"]`

Comment: The label is just an example. I knwo it should be as you said. By i want to do it for every element. :)

Comment: Further note that you both `var Label` and `function Label`, i.e. you have an identifier conflict; one of these will win (the var) and the other gets overwritten

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
ID on page should be unique for good practics. If you want to fetch multiple labels then use attribute such as: "data-*" or "class".
For example:

- Fetch all inputs which have class "name"

`$("input.name");`

- Fetch label by ID "myID":

`$("label#myID");`

Performance tip: better is to use selector `label#myID` than `#myID`

Comment: Yes my all the Id are unique in my html form. The issue is how to make each function to accept only its respective element.